# Add multiple rows to MultiIndex DataFrame at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Imagine that we have an experiment with multiple subjects and multiple trials per subject, and each trial produces an unknown number of "events" for two measurement methods A and B. Now we want to store that in a DataFrame using MultiIndex:

```py
tuples = [
    ('s1', 't1', 0, 1, 11), ('s1', 't2', 0, 4, 14), ('s1', 't2', 1, 5, 15), ('s2', 't1', 0, 6, 16),
    ('s2', 't1', 1, 7, 17), ('s2', 't2', 0, 8, 18), ('s2', 't3', 0, 9, 19),
]
df= pd.DataFrame.from_records(tuples, index=['subject', 'trial', 'event'],
                              columns=['subject', 'trial', 'event', 'A', 'B'])
print(df)
```

The DataFrame looks like this. Note how we have different numbers of trials and events for each subject.

```
                     A   B
subject trial event       
s1      t1    0      1  11
        t2    0      4  14
              1      5  15
s2      t1    0      6  16
              1      7  17
        t2    0      8  18
        t3    0      9  19
```

Now suppose that we want to add the events for subject 3, trial 1, method A:

```py
events = [5,6,7] # List of unknown length, generated by some algorithm
for i, event in enumerate(events):
    df.loc[('s3', 't1', i), 'A'] = events[i]
print(df)
```

This works, but adding things to a data structure in a loop is always a bad idea, because it creates a lot of unnecessary copies of the whole dataframe. Imagine doing this for thousands of events and hundreds of trials...

```
                       A     B
subject trial event           
s1      t1    0      1.0  11.0
        t2    0      4.0  14.0
              1      5.0  15.0
s2      t1    0      6.0  16.0
              1      7.0  17.0
        t2    0      8.0  18.0
        t3    0      9.0  19.0
s3      t1    0      5.0   NaN
              1      6.0   NaN
              2      7.0   NaN
```

So there must be better method... however, I couldn't find one. Here's what I tried so far, but none of the approaches really worked. Granted, I didn't really expect most of them to work. At the end I got frustrated and just tried random combinations of syntax, because I found the ["MultiIndex / advanced indexing"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) documentation a bit hard to understand.

```
df.loc[('s3','t2'), 'A'] = events    # --> KeyError: ('s3', 't2')
df.loc[('s3','t2', slice(None)), 'A'] = events    # --> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
df.loc[('s3','t2', [0,1,2]), 'A'] = events    # --> KeyError: ('s3', 't2', [0, 1, 2])
df.loc[('s4','t2', [0,1,2]), 'A'] = events    # --> KeyError: 's4'
df.loc['s3','t2',:] = events    # KeyError: ('s3', 't2', slice(None, None, None))
df['s3', 't2', :] = events    # ValueError: Length of values (3) does not match length of index (10)
df['s3', 't2'] = events    # ValueError: Length of values (3) does not match length of index (10)
df[('s3','t2'):] = events    # ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (0,2)
```

Or is this just the wrong tool for the job? In the end, I want to compare A and B for some subsets of data, so Pandas' flexible querying should come in handy.

In the past, I did most of this using lists and dicts of RecordClass instances containing numpy arrays, and selected data using list comprehensions.

Comment: create a new dataframe from the new data and `concat`, don't append one row at a time. Something like: `new_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': events}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('s3','t1',i) for i in range(len(events))]))`.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can do it like this:

```
events = [5,6,7] 
num_of_events = len(events)
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['S3']*num_of_events,['ti']*num_of_events,range(num_of_events)])
df_out = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(events, index=idx, columns=['A'])])
```

Output:

```
                     A     B
subject trial event         
s1      t1    0      1  11.0
        t2    0      4  14.0
              1      5  15.0
s2      t1    0      6  16.0
              1      7  17.0
        t2    0      8  18.0
        t3    0      9  19.0
S3      ti    0      5   NaN
              1      6   NaN
              2      7   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems quite verbose and technical for what superficially appears to be such a simple operation: *"Set these rows or add them if they don't exist"*. (explicitly mentioning the length multiple times, spreading out the specification of the desired indices across multiple rows, explicitly construction a new MutliIndex, etc). But if this is the simplest method, then I guess that this is not an intended use case for Pandas. Or at least it was not considered important/useful enough.

Comment: @Fritz, I think that fact that you can have any values in any of those index level labels, i.e. there is no "default" value assign for index labels at various index levels, you need to explicitly defined what those index labels are for each level.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct (although one could conceivably use `range(N)` as a default, as `pd.DataFrame(['a','b','c'])` does for example). Specifying all indices explicitly is also what I tried, for example with `df.loc[('s4','t2', [0,1,2]), 'A'] = events`, which seems unambiguous enough from my perspective. That's why I suspect that it just wasn't considered relevant or important enough by the Pandas devs.